# Why scaler.inverse_transform returns different values for the same inputs in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My data set has one output that I call Y and 5 inputs called X. I read the output and input in from my system in python which are stored in an array called FinalArray.

Later one I use StandardScaler from sklearn to scale my data set as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(FinalArray)
FinalArrayScaled = scaler.transform(FinalArray)
```

FinalArrayScaled is later on divided into train and test as it is usually recommended for regression techniques. Since I am using surrogate models (more specifically Kriging) I am implementing infill to add more points to my sample domain to improve the confidence in my model (RSME and r^2). The infill method returns the values needed scaled. Remember that the input used for the Surrogate model has been scaled previously.

Here is a short example of how the output looks like for 4 samples and 5 features (Image 1)[image]

The first column (0) represents the output of the system and the other columns represent the input of my system. So, each raw represent a specific experiment.

In order to know the values with the appropriate dimensions, I implemented the scaler.inverse_transform on the output of the method. However, the output seems weird because once I apply the method scaler.inverse_transform I obtained very different values for the same input, refer to Figure 2.
[image]

Notice the elements (0,1) and (0,2) from Figure 1. Although they are exactly the same the lead to totally different values in Figure 2. The same applies to many others. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug on my source code. For the sake of completeness, I am sharing the final results herein.

[image]

I had an error in a for loop. I wanted to erase the question to avoid confusions in the future but I was not able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: You can always delete your own questions as long as they don't have upvoted answers,  which I kindly suggest that you do; your answer has actually not answered anything possibly useful for others, probably because your question is not reproducible...